# How to increase (or access) Go bleve search engine results?

Tags: go, search, bleve

When I try to make a search query with [bleve](https://github.com/blevesearch/bleve) I always get 10 or less results. How can I increase this limit or make a search between all the data?

Here is code example, where I expect to get 35 results, but getting 10 (ps `calc.Rand()` function is giving random bytes):

```golang
package search

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/blevesearch/bleve/v2"
)

func TestSearcher(t *testing.T) {
    mapping := bleve.NewIndexMapping()
    searcher, _ := bleve.New("search/src", mapping)
    for i := 0; i < 35; i++ {
        searcher.Index(string(calc.Rand()), "stuff")
    }

    query := bleve.NewMatchQuery("stuff")
    search := bleve.NewSearchRequest(query)
    searchRez, _ := searcher.Search(search)
    t.Error(len(searchRez.Hits))
}
```

Result I get:

```sh
--- FAIL: TestSearcher (2.33s)
    /Users/ ... /search/search_test.go:86: 10
```

Result I expect:

```sh
--- FAIL: TestSearcher (2.33s)
    /Users/ ... /search/search_test.go:86: 35
```

How do I access all the 35 values, that are stored by this index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the field `Size` on [`SearchRequest`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/blevesearch/bleve/v2#SearchRequest):

> Size/From describe how much and which part of the result set to return.

```
    search := bleve.NewSearchRequest(query)
    search.Size = 35 // or the page size you want

    searchRez, _ := searcher.Search(search)
    fmt.Println(len(searchRez.Hits)) // prints 35
```

or with pagination, you set the field `From` incrementally based on page size. A contrived example:

```
    count, _ := searcher.DocCount()
    for i := 0; i < int(count); i += 10 /* page size */ {
        search.From = i
        searchRez, _ := searcher.Search(search)
        fmt.Println(len(searchRez.Hits)) // prints 10 10 10 5
    }
```